# Clustered SQL database requires full recovery mode?

Tags: windows, sql-server, sql, cluster

The application we provide customers with requires an SQL database. Due to the nature of the application, we recommend the recovery mode to be set to Simple as it is not critical data that is stored. One of our customers is using this in a Windows Cluster and have the recovery mode set to Full. When asking them to change this they said that "In a Cluster, the recovery mode for an SQL database must be set to Full". When probing for more info they just said that "that's the way it is". I haven't been able to find any information on Microsoft articles that backs this statement.

**Question**
Does clustered SQL installations require Full Recovery Mode? If so, why?

**EDIT**: This is an active-active cluster, but it would be interesting to know both the situation of an active-active and an active-passive cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, clustering is independent of database recovery model. The two factors are unrelated. There is no link. So you won't see this in any documentation: it is not a [*pre-requisite*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910(v=sql.120).aspx) of clustering

Note, *database mirroring* requires full recovery model for the mirrored database, but this is not clustering.

Edit, I see where the confusion comes from...

Clustering itself does not require full recovery but "Availability" databases in AlwaysOn Groups do. 
However, *Failover Clustering* is **not** *AlwaysOn*. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929171(v=sql.120).aspx for more

That is, I can cluster SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition but I can't use AlwaysOn which requires Enterprise Edition. Therefore, I don't need full recovery model

Comment: Ah, thank you, as I suspected :) In order to explain this with backing information, do you perhaps have a link to some Microsoft article confirming this?

Comment: I linked already, It does not say full recovery is required. Like it does for [mirroring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366349.aspx)